# How to do image overlay and watermark using node.js in amazon lambda function

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have images hosted on amazons3 server.my client wants to process the images using amazon lambda function. I have followed the example: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/walkthrough-s3-events-adminuser-create-test-function-create-function.html

It is fine for resizing. But I want overlay and watermarking for the images also.But not getting a way.I have tried with imagemagick[https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm] for it seems to take path as parameter and the s3 image path is not helping me. the obvious reason I think is that they can't be directly accessed as the images paths in the directory.

Any suggestion on how to achieve this. I stuck for last 3 days but not able move forward.Thanks in advance for help!!!!

Comment: You have to first read the file from s3, then process it, then upload to S3 the watermarked image

Comment: I am reading the file from s3 and getting buffer as output. So how to process the buffer to get an overlay image.@Max

Comment: With gm like you said. Have you encountered issues with it?

Comment: Yes.Which gm method to use and how I am confused. I am thinking of using gm.composite() method for overlaying but it accepts only image path. But the image is on S3 and it can not be made public.So not able to get the image from the path. through s3.getobject() I am getting image buffer.So how to process with that.

Comment: Oh I understand the question now. You should save the file you downloaded from S3 and then give the path to `gm`. The file will be deleted when Lambda finishes, so make sure to upload the processed file back to S3 before the Lambda finishes.

Comment: The server part is not with us. I mean client has control over it. We have only the lambda function and CLI commands to check the log and S3 browser to know the resultant image. So saving the file, means?? and how to save that on server using lambda function.Any help.

Comment: In the lambda. Save the buffer to the file system, run gm, and upload to S3. All from lambda

Comment: How can I do that. Do you have link for that. Again the file will be saved on the server as I think. am I right?

Comment: Your lambda code, written in Node.js can access the Lambda file system using `fs` module

Comment: Did you ever get a fully working solution for this? 

This is what I'm trying to do for the watermarking (and putting the png file used for this in the same package as the js code for the lambda function) but it doesn't work. The resizing happens correctly but the watermarking fails.

https://gist.github.com/madewulf/0e53b5117141d76da6cc

Comment: No not yet. I have tries with d3.js but it's having some problem so not working. But I have found the solution for overlay images.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your are trying to do the overlaying in the size action. A quick check over at the [gm repository on GitHub](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm) showed an [issue with a possible solution](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm/issues/276). It seems as thought the composite action accepts a stream to read from. In regards to your code I would suggest a refactor to chain the actions together. I'm not sure I understand where the write stream is going in your original function though. Let me know if this helps!

```
var scalingFactor = Math.min(
  newSize / size.width,
  newSize / size.height
);

var width  = scalingFactor * size.width;
var height = scalingFactor * size.height;

gm(response.Body)
.autoOrient()
.resize(width, height)
.gravity('SouthEast')
.draw('image Over 0,0 0,0 ' + getAppPath() + '/path/to/wm-bas.png')
.stream('PNG') // This converts the whole thing to a png, not sure if you want this
.pipe(writeStream) // Change this
```